# Create data file according to a schema

Tags: java, file, xls

I want to create a data file that has to be pipe saperated. The data in the file is going be populate using beans the data. The data file has to be according to a xls schema.

please help

Comment: So what prevents you to create that pipe separated data file? Did you try something? What concrete problems occurred? It is not easy to help you if you give us so few information. So far I only can say: Write a program to export your data in the requested format.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create "xls" file you can use http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Initilally we were creating a huge xml file using dom model, then this is converted file is converted to a text file with pipe saperated data from the xml, this is also validated acording to the xls. Now I want to remove the overhead of creating the xml, I just want to directly convert data into text file